# Compiler behavior and "register storage class specifier is deprecated"

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-warnings

I'm testing some C++ code with `-std=c++11`. I noticed a warning I had not seen before:

> 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated

What does the standard say about this (other than its deprecated)?

Is it implementation defined?

Will compilers take it as a hint and try to put the value in a register?

Will this eventually lead to a compile failure?

Perhaps something else?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: `clang++` gives this warning but `g++` not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++11, **[dcl.stc]**:

> 3 - A `register` specifier is a hint to the implementation that the variable so declared will be heavily used. [ *Note:* The hint can be ignored and in most implementations it will be ignored if the address of the variable
>   is taken. This use is deprecated (see D.2). *— end note* ]

There is a proposal to remove the `register` keyword as a storage specifier, while reserving it as a keyword: [Remove Deprecated Use of the `register` Keyword (n4340)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4340). This may or may not be implemented in C++1z (tentative C++17); it would pose challenges for compatibility with C, where `register` still has semantic effect (a C `register` variable or parameter cannot have its address taken or be subject to array-to-pointer decay).

Answer (score 5):

> Is it implementation defined?

It always was.

> Will compilers take it as a hint and try to put the value in a register?

It's implementation-defined.

> Will this eventually lead to a compile failure?

No.

**EDIT** Perhaps I misunderstood the question about the eventual compile failure. I took it to mean an eventual failure in the current compilation. If the question is about the future of the `register` keyword, anything is possible: I don't care to fortune-tell.

Comment: According to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4340 and https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-lenexa-may-2015/, it looks like `register` is planned to be removed entirely, which means it may eventually lead to compile failure.